# Combining two Gaussians into another Guassian

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

In the code below I have two Gaussian one red and the other in a purple curve. I am wondering if there is a way in python to combining both Gaussian unto a third curve which is suppose to look like the blue curve (which just serves as an example of a Gaussian supposedly being higher and wider)? Any help will be appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def gauss(x, p): # p[0]==mean, p[1]==stdev, p[2]==heightg, p[3]==baseline                   
    a = p[2]
    mu = p[0]
    sig = p[1]
    base = p[3]
    return a * np.exp(-1.0 * ((x - mu)**2.0) / (2.0 * sig**2.0)) + base

p0 = [6804.5, 1.2, 23.0, 25.3532] # Inital guess is a normal distribution
p02 = [6804.5, 6.5, 5.0, 25.09098]

xp = np.linspace(6780, 6810, 200)
fig = plt.figure()
a1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
a1.plot(xp, gauss(xp, p0), lw=3, alpha=2.5, color='r')
a1.plot(xp, gauss(xp, p02), lw=3, alpha=2.5, color='purple')
a1.set_xlim([6798, 6810])

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "combine"?  Why not just add the curves: `gauss(xp,p0) + gauss(xp,p02)`?

Comment: @tom10. Because you cannot add two probability densities to get another probability density (the integral would not be 1, obviously). When you **add** two **random variables**, the resulting density is the **convolution** of their **densities**. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions) for more.

Comment: As an aside, I get an error with your code, which I can overcome by removing the two "alpha=2.5".
The error says:
*ValueError: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.5)
number in rbga sequence outside 0-1 range*

Comment: @arbautjc: I'm trying to get at what the OP means by "combine".  A Gaussian curve is not necessarily a probability distribution (and the integral of the curves shown is not 1).  What "combine" means depends entirely on the (unexplained) context, and neither convolving nor adding are going to produce the blue curve from the red and purple curves, so it's still a mystery.

Comment: @user1821176: the blue curve looks more like the red curve convolved with itself.  Is that fair game for the answer?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the blue curve, but I'm guessing you're looking for the distribution of the the sum of the two independent gaussians

If

```
X1 ~ Gaussian(mean1,std1), and X2 ~ Gaussian(mean2, std2),
```

Then

```
X1+X2 ~ Gaussian(mean1+mean2, sqrt(std1^2 + std2^2))
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you are looking for the convolution of the two Gaussians? In this case you can make use of the function numpy.convolve (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html#numpy.convolve). Note that the output array will be twize the length of the two input arrays. This is related to the definition of this convolution, where the functions are kind of shifted along each other. See Wikipedia for a nice illustration showing differences between convolution, cross-correlation and auto-corellation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution